# Debugging in rails or Printing variable value to log in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to ruby.

This is my model(I am following an example from the book "Agile development using Rails 4")

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items,dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item =line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)

    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item=line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end

end
```

This is giving me error "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass" on the line "current_item.quantity += 1"

The code is written by hand and not a copy paste. I dont want to do a copy paste because I am going to learn the hard way.

I understood that the current_item is not having nil, if that is the case it will execute the else part.But again the error is saying its a nilClass. I am confused. How will I debug the problem. I would like to know a way to print the current_item,product_id to the development log or console.

The call is comming from the line_item controller

```
def create
    product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
                      notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action:new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive, `current_item.quantity` returns `nil`.

Comment: So it is saying the quantity is nil and not the current_item? if yes i seriously look like a fool to miss that :(

Comment: No, `current_item` probably returns correct object, but its `quantity` is `nil`.

Comment: ok is there a way to print the values in the current_item into the console from a modal as an array? I am looking something like print_r from php

Comment: Honestly, there are much better ways to debug your code in Ruby than printing output into the log - look at `pry`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, It was a pleasant conversation. have a nice day